# XQuery in SQL server doing SUM over zero value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm trying to extract monetary sums stored in some poorly formated xml columns (there is no schema defined for the XML column which I guess is part of the problem). I'm getting a conversion error whenever I encounter a node with 0 as its value.

Example:

```
select xml.value('sum(/List/value)', 'numeric') sum
from (select cast('<List><value>1</value><value>2</value></List>' as xml) xml) a
```

gives the sum 3 while:

```
select xml.value('sum(/List/value)', 'numeric') sum
from (select cast('<List><value>0</value><value>0</value></List>' as xml) xml) a
```

raises the error: "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Any idea how I can make my query return 0 when summing up a list of zero-valued nodes?

Comment: It seems that sum(/List/value) returns a float "0.0E0" when the sum is zero and that number cannot be converted to numeric. Any idea why I see this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comment suggests an answer to your problem.

Instead of converting to numeric, convert to float.  Scientific notation will convert to float.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across this question, and ultimately an answer, while looking at a similar issue with integers. Despite the delay since the last answer, I'm adding here in case it helps anyone else in future.

First your basic answer:

```
select xml.value('xs:decimal(sum(/List/value))', 'numeric') sum
from (select cast('<List><value>0</value><value>0</value></List>' as xml) xml) a
```

In XQuery you can cast the value to a standard XML Schema type, which will then be handled correctly by SQL Server.

PLEASE NOTE: the default "numeric" in SQL Server does not have any decimal places(scale of "0")! You probably intended to do something more like:

```
select xml.value('xs:decimal(sum(/List/value))', 'numeric(20,5))') sum
from (select cast('<List><value>0</value><value>0</value></List>' as xml) xml) a
```

(you cannot get SQL Server to infer the precision or scale from the value returned from the Xml, you must explicitly specify it)

Finally, the actual issue that I personally needed to address was almost exactly the same, except I was dealing with integers, which also struggle with the xml representation of "0" `double` values:

```
select xml.value('xs:int(sum(/List/value))', 'int') sum
from (select cast('<List><value>0</value><value>0</value></List>' as xml) xml) a
```

**UPDATE:** The problem with the decimal-handling solution I posted above (converting to decimal in XQuery before SQL gets to parsing the value) is that the *aggregation* actually happens with the (assumed/inferred) floating point (double) data type. If the values you have stored in your Xml require a high degree of precision, this may actually be the wrong thing to do - the floating-point aggregation may actually result in a loss of data. EG here we lose the last digit of the number we are summing:

```
select xml.value('xs:decimal(sum(/List/value))', 'numeric(28, 0)') sum
from (select cast('<List>
        <value>1000000000000000000000000001</value>
        <value>1000000000000000000000000001</value>
    </List>' as xml) xml) a
```

(comes out to "2000000000000000000000000000", which is wrong)

This issue equally applies to other approaches offered here, such as explicitly reading the value as "float" in T-SQL.

To avoid this, here's a final option using an XQuery FLWOR expression to set the data type *before* the aggregation operation. In this case, the aggregation occurs correctly, and we have the correct summed value (while also handling "0" values if/when they occur):

```
select xml.value('sum(for $r in /List/value return xs:decimal($r))', 'numeric(28, 0)') sum
from (select cast('<List>
        <value>1000000000000000000000000001</value>
        <value>1000000000000000000000000001</value>
    </List>' as xml) xml) a
```

(comes out to "2000000000000000000000000002", the correct value)

Comment: I like the method here of using XQuery to cast the value to a standard XML Schema type. That was exactly what I was looking for, and prefer that over converting it to a float, and then back to something else. It's a bit more explicit, but I can avoid moving it to one type and then to another, and I think that's clearer.

Answer (score 4):

you can also use and if statement like this:

```
@x.value('if (sum(/List/value) = 0) then 0 else sum(/List/value)', 'numeric')
```